# Dividir un String

Tags: java, string

Tengo un `string` que recibo de una báscula, del cual necesito substraer los valores de peso que éste contiene. Usé la función `split()` para dividir el `string` en tres partes. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo substraer solamente los valores de peso, quitando todo lo demás del `string`?

Mi código es el siguiente

```
String str = "ST  A011     0.00kg  A012     0.00kg  A013       0.00kg";

String[] parts = str.split("kg");
String part1=parts[0]; // ST  A011     0.00
String part2=parts[1]; // A012     0.00
String part3=parts[2]; // A013     0.00
```

Lo que busco sería:

```
String part1=parts[0]=0.00
String part2=parts[1]=0.00
String part3=parts[2]=0.00
```

Comment: siempre don double?

Comment: si siempre se recibe de esa forma

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hacer y qué problema te has encontrado? Por favor, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manteniendo tú código tal cual como esta puedes hacer:

```
String str = "ST  A011     0.00kg  A012     0.00kg  A013       0.00kg";

String[] parts = str.split("kg");
String part1=parts[0]; // ST  A011     0.00
String part2=parts[1]; // A012     0.00
String part3=parts[2]; // A013     0.00

part1 = part1.substring(part1.indexOf("A011") + 4).trim();
part2 = part2.substring(part2.indexOf("A012") + 4).trim();
part3 = part3.substring(part3.indexOf("A013") + 4).trim();
```

Con el **`substring`** estamos descartando todo lo que está antes de los `0.00`, el `+ 4` porque cada `A011, A012, A013` tienen un tamaño de 4, por lo cual hay que sumarlo al índice de la primera coincidencia de `A011, A012, A013` respectivamente y el **`trim`** para eliminar los espacios en blancos que sobren.

> [substring](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-substring-example/): método devuelve una nueva cadena que es una subcadena de esta `string. substring()`.
>
> [indexOf](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-indexof-method-example/): devuelve el índice de un determinado carácter o cadena como argumento del método. Si el argumento no se encuentra en la cadena, el método devuelve -1. El contador de índice para una cadena comienza desde cero.

Comment: muchas gracias si funciono